# PHP/MySQL - Rank on Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, join, rank

My query at the moment:

```
SELECT * FROM posts as p
INNER JOIN users as u
ON p.author = u.uid
INNER JOIN usergroups as ug
ON u.usergroup = ug.gid
WHERE tid_parent = ?
```

This query, for example will provide the following data:

[image: http://gyazo.com/e2ce3d53698fef66bc18a0ea9ce84756.png]

I'd like a rank beside these (using **@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank** maybe).

Comment: Rank isnt showing in your image. Can you show all the fields in your SQL?

Comment: Hi, Mike. I would like to add rank to that list. Sorry for not explaining my problem!

Comment: Is rank in your table or are you looking to derive it somehow?

Comment: I'd like to add rank to my table. For example, post 1 on a topic would be rank 1, post 2 would be rank 2 and so forth. But this can change, e.g. post ID 1,002 might be rank 3 on a topic.

Comment: So if I understand you will have to add the field to the `posts` table. This is common practice often it would be called `display_order` or similar

Comment: I'd like to use the SET (AT)rank = 0; (AT)rank := (AT)rank + 1 AS rank SQL function to count each row number individually.

Comment: Can you do it in PHP it would be easier?

Answer (score 0):

When your looping out your table keep a count and print the count value as the rank

```
 $c=1;
 foreach($results as $result){
   //all the table row html
   echo $c;
   //all rest of table row html
   $c++;
  }
```

Comment: I have pages (GET: &page=2 for e.g.). That resets it.

Comment: Didn't get that at all

Comment: Oh now I did. Then do some maths to figure out where $c starts dude. You know the page number and the number of items you show per page shouldn't be too hard to figure out

Comment: Actually, it's funny you said so because it's the other way round aha. I need to find what page number the post is on.

Comment: How can you? Your user or your app determine the page to display. If your script doesn't know how can it show any page except the first? Makes no sense